# Random number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate an array with a random number that each number is different. Could someone help me to solve this? Thanks.

```
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0;i < 5; i++){
            var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            array.push(a);
        }
        console.log(array);
```

Comment: Make an array of unique numbers: `[0,1,2,3,4]` - then shuffle that array using your algorithm of choice (Fisher-Yates Shuffle recommended). This will ensure the results are unique.

Comment: The logic you are applying will work just instead of multiplying with 5 , multiply with a multiple of 10 eg. 100000. Number of zeroes equal to number of digits you want for random number.

Comment: Here for example result [0, 0, 4, 2, 0] . I want every number in this array is different  such as [1,4,2,0,3]

Comment: `set = new Set(); while (set.size < 5) set.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  while (array.indexOf(a) !== -1) {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  array.push(a);
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

with this implementation you will be sure you are not going to add more than one time an existing number inside `var array`.

```js
var array = [];

function randomNumber(array) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var found = array.filter(el => el == a);
    if(found.length) return randomNumber(array);
    return a;
}

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    array.push(randomNumber(array));
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns a number a floating point number between 0 & 1.  So multiplying with a 5 and then doing `Math.floor` can result a number between 0 & 4. Hence you array may contain duplicate number

```js
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var a = parseInt(Math.random() * i * 100, 10);
  array.push(a);
}
console.log(array);
```